# Box border for each letter inside span

Tags: html, css

I have a span like below

```
    <span style="font-size:18px; font-weight:bold;">8342</span>
```

How can I put a black box around each number inside that span using css?

I want it just like below image

[image]

Comment: You can’t. You need to wrap every single digit into an element of its own first.

Comment: Ok thanks, but this question is not worth downvoting I think

Comment: Other than using JavaScript to split the characters up, Razia's answer is your only option.

Answer (score 1):

Please check this  **[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/feb8potd/)**

```
<span style="font-size:18px; font-weight:bold;" class="test">8342</span>

.pwn{
 border: 2px solid black ;
  display: inline;  
}

var text= $(".test").html();
 $(".test").html('');
for(i=0;i<=text.length-1; i++)
{
var html = text.substr(i,1);
var sp="<span style='font-size:18px; font-weight:bold;' class='pwn'>" + html
sp+=" </span> &nbsp;";
$(".test").append(sp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its possible but a little complicated.
You need the font **monospace** and a background-image, you put every letter in an other span or you split every letter up in javascript!
Here is a solution without javascript:

```css
span{
    background-image: url("http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-4oAWWCcNNz4/Tjr3nKNyVUI/AAAAAAAAPLU/Pouua-pNsEY/s1600/sq.gif");   
    background-size: 20px;
    font-family: monospace;
    font-size: 13px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    letter-spacing: 12px;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
 <span>8342</span>
```

**Note:** This doesn't work on IE11. It doesn't load the image.

I hope i could help you^^

Answer (score -1):

Try this:-

```css
span{
 border: 2px solid black ;
  display: inline;  
}
```

```html
   <span style="font-size:18px; font-weight:bold; color:red">8</span>
   <span style="font-size:18px; font-weight:bold; color:red">3</span>
   <span style="font-size:18px; font-weight:bold; color:red">4</span>
   <span style="font-size:18px; font-weight:bold; color:red">2</span>
```

Comment: I am not going to use separate span for each number, as the data comes from service as whole